# An elegant way to ignore any errors thrown by a method

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I'm removing a temporary file with `NSFileManager` like this:

```
let fm = NSFileManager()
fm.removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
// error: "Call can throw but it is not marked with 'try'"
```

I don't really care if the file is there when the call is made and if it's already removed, so be it.

What would be an elegant way to tell Swift to ignore any thrown errors, without using `do/catch`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you don't care about success or not then you can call

```
let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
_ = try? fm.removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
```

From ["Error Handling"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) in the Swift documentation:

> You use `try?` to handle an error by converting it to an optional value.
>   If an error is thrown while evaluating the `try?` expression, the value
>   of the expression is `nil`.

The `removeItemAtURL()` returns "nothing" (aka `Void`), therefore the return value of the `try?` expression is `Optional<Void>`.
Assigning this return value to `_` avoids a *"result of 'try?' is unused"* warning.

If you are only interested in the outcome of the call but not in
the particular error which was thrown then you can test the
return value of `try?` against `nil`:

```
if (try? fm.removeItemAtURL(fileURL)) == nil {
    print("failed")
}
```

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 3 (Xcode 8),** you don't need the dummy assignment, at least not in this particular case:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file")
let fm = FileManager.default
try? fm.removeItem(at: fileURL)
```

compiles without warnings.

Comment: Thanks. This is surely the most elegant way. But still it looks weird and inconsistent because expressions containig optional chaining like "foo?.bar()" don't bring up warnings about returned and unused optional Void values. Why should "try?" do? I hope Apple will fix this with some further Swift version.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. !!

Comment: I'm still getting used to switching from ObjC to Swift. What exactly is happening here regarding the question mark: `_ = try? fm.removeItemAtURL(fileURL)`. Is that telling the compiler to just use nil if an error is thrown?

Comment: @pnizzle: Yes, as quoted above: *“If an error is thrown while evaluating the try? expression, the value of the expression is nil.”*