# Why can’t I use guard when setting AVAudioSession category?

Tags: swift, swift2, guard

This is a simple Swift 2.0 question, hopefully with a simple answer:

Why does the following code give an error “Ambiguous reference to member setCategory”:

```
guard AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient) else {
    //
}
```

Yet this code does not throw that error:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
} catch {
     //
}
```

I don’t intend to take any action if this call doesn’t fail, but I’d still prefer not to use `try!` – so can I `guard` this statement? Or, have I misunderstood `guard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) documentation:

> **Early exit**
>   A `guard` statement, like an `if` statement, executes statements depending
>   on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a `guard` statement to
>   require that a condition must be true in order for the code after the
>   guard statement to be executed.

A typical example is

```
guard <someCondition> else { return }
```

to "early return" from a function if a condition is not met.

But throwing functions are not Boolean expressions,
they *must* be called in some "try context", as documented in
[Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html):

> **Handling Errors**
>   When a function throws an error, it changes the flow of your program,
>   so it’s important that you can quickly identify places in your code
>   that can throw errors. To identify these places in your code, write
>   the `try` keyword—or the `try?` or `try!` variation—before a piece of code
>   that calls a function, method, or initializer that can throw an error.

So this are completely different things. The `guard` statement
cannot be used with throwing functions.

If you don't care about success or failure of a throwing function,
use `try?` and ignore the result as in
[An elegant way to ignore any errors thrown by a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788155/an-elegant-way-to-ignore-any-errors-thrown-by-a-method). In your case:

```
_ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```