# Use the try? operator to make the code more concise

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2, try-catch

I have this code in Swift 2 to move a file to a new destination, overwriting if necessary:

```
let origin = "...", destination = "..."
do {
   try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(destination)  // remove existing file
} catch {}
do {
   try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(origin, toPath: destination)
} catch {}
```

To make the code more concise, and since I don't care about the error thrown, I thought of using the `try?` operator as follows:

```
let origin = "...", destination = "..."
try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(destination)
try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(origin, toPath: destination)
```

This creates a compiler warning that the result of the operation is being unused, so I have to add an unused `let` and it looks awful:

```
...
let _ = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(origin, toPath: destination)
```

Is it bad to let the warnings there in the sake of conciseness?

Comment: *"Is it bad to let the warnings there in the sake of conciseness?"* – Most people would probably say "yes", but you (or your company) has to decide that. Note that you don't need the `let`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788155/an-elegant-way-to-ignore-any-errors-thrown-by-a-method

Comment: _ = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(origin, toPath: destination)

Comment: Thank you, that sounds a little better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 it is legal to ignore the result without the extra assignment. This compiles just fine, with no warning, in the Xcode 8 GM:

```
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: destination)
```

(Earlier, by the way, I asked about this on bugs.swift.org, and was told directly that this `_ = try?`
syntax is regarded as correct and is a small price to pay for acknowledging to the compiler — and yourself — that you are deliberately ignoring the returned value. So what you are doing is just fine while you remain in the Swift 2 world!)

Comment: It's legal but bad practice.

Comment: @mixel I don't agree that it's necessarily bad practice. There are situations where no useful info is returned, so there's nothing to capture, and you may genuinely not care whether you failed. Working with an AVAudioSession is a case in point.

Comment: @Iree I'll add some of that stuff back in, then, if you think it is good for posterity.

Comment: @matt I understand. In that case adding `_ = ` says "I do not care about returning value" to other developers. Otherwise they will get `Result of 'try?' is unused'` warning and will be confused. Code should be self-documented.

Comment: @mixel But my point is that in Swift 3 there is no such warning. Added that in, in case I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Does this whole new 1 line `try?` mean: *Obviously since I know running this func could throw an error. I have to use catch, though I don't care to catch the error, so I'm just gonna write in a simple one liner?*

Comment: @matt Yes, because in iOS 10 SDK / Swift 3 `FileManager.removeItem` has `Void` return type. But OP uses iOS 9 SDK / Swift 2 and there `NSFileManager.removeItemAtPath` returns `Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have these warnings because you are calling some method and you do not handle returning value.

If you do not need returning value then you should use `let _ =` syntax to explicitly say to everyone else who reads this code that returning value is ignored intentionally.

Otherwise if you should handle returning value but you did not do that yet because you are too lazy or by some other reason then it's considered to be a bug in your software and you definitely should not suppress it.