# Optional try for function with no return value

Tags: swift, error-handling

Could it be that when using `try?` (optional try) for the call of a throwing function with no return value the errors are just ignored?

```
func throwingVoidFunction() throws { . . . }

try? throwingVoidFunction()
```

I expected that the compiler does not allow a `try?` in front of a throwing function with return type `void`, but the compiler doesn't complain.

So is using `try?` in front of a void function a way to absorb errors? (like when using an empty default catch: `catch {}`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason for the compiler to complain. The return type
of

```
func throwingVoidFunction() throws { ... }
```

is `Void` and therefore the type of the expression

```
try? throwingVoidFunction()
```

is `Optional<Void>`, and its value is `nil` (`== Optional<Void>.none`) if an error was thrown while evaluating the expression,
and `Optional<Void>.some()` otherwise.

You can ignore the return value or test it against `nil`. An
example is given in [An elegant way to ignore any errors thrown by a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788155/an-elegant-way-to-ignore-any-errors-thrown-by-a-method):

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file")
let fm = FileManager.default
try? fm.removeItem(at: fileURL)
```

Comment: Bad isn't it bad style to simply ignore a thrown error?

Comment: @user1364368: You are generally right. In this particular case, the most probable error would be that the file did not exist, and you might not care about that. Anyway, it is just an example for what you asked about.

Comment: There is also a cartoon on the issue of simply ignoring errors: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/07/30/coders-weaknesses-1-the-trycatch/

Comment: @user1364368: It was not my intention to recommend that you ignore errors.

Comment: @FadiAbuzant: How does it "not work"? Compiler errors? Runtime errors?